# Evaluating worst case RAM effective bandwidth with discontinous memory access

Tags: multithreading, cpu, ram, bandwidth, latency

I'm trying to evaluate the effective memory "bandwidth" (throughput in bytes of data being treated) from main memory to CPU in a worst case scenario: the RAM cache is made totally inefficient due to long distances in the successive addresses being treated. As far as I understand what matters here is the RAM latency and not its bandwidth (which is the throughput when transferring big continuous blocks of data).

The scenario is this (say you work with 64 bits=8 bytes values):

- you read data at an address
- make some light weight CPU computation (so that CPU is not the bottleneck)
- then you read data at new address quite far-away from the first one
- and so on

I'd like to have an idea of the throughput (say in bytes). A simple calculation assuming the RAM has typical DDR3 13 ns latency yields a bandwidth of 8 B/ 13 ns = 600 MB/s. But this raises several points:

- is this reasoning (at least schematically) correct?
- is the time to get data exactly the RAM latency or do you have to add some time related to cache, CPU or any component in-between? Do you know how much?
- what happens when doing this in multiple threads? Would there be 600 MB bandwidth for all threads together of for each of them?

Comment: RAM has complex internal organization, and there is difference between accesses to same physical RAM row and into different rows (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_timings - closed row need some R* timings, and open row can be accesed with CAS). 7-cpu has some benchmarks: https://www.7-cpu.com/; and lmbench has good test lat_mem_rd: http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/lat_mem_rd.8.html. Yes, there is some additional time to send data from memory contorller to pipeline, check tables https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/SandyBridge.html. Also https://www.ece.cmu.edu/~safari/thesis/kchang_defense_slides.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... effective memory "bandwidth" ... from main memory to CPU in a worst case scenario:

There are two "worst" scenarios: memory accesses which don't use (miss) CPU caches and memory accesses which accesses too far addresses and can't reuse open DRAM rows.

> the RAM cache

The cache is not part of RAM, it is part of CPU, and named [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) (top part of [memory hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hierarchy)).

> is made totally inefficient due to long distances in the successive addresses being treated.

Modern CPU caches has many builtin [hardware prefetchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_prefetching#Methods_of_hardware_prefetching), which may detect non-random steps between several memory accesses. Many prefretchers will detect any step inside aligned 4 kilobyte (KB) page: if you access address1, then address1 + 256 bytes, then L1 prefetcher will start access of address1 + 256*2, address1 + 256*3 etc. Some prefetchers may try to predict out of 4 KB range. So, using only long distances between accesses may be not enough. (prefetchers may be disabled https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/disclosure-of-hw-prefetcher-control-on-some-intel-processors)

> As far as I understand what matters here is the RAM latency and not its bandwidth

Yes, there are some modes when RAM accesses are latency limited.

> The scenario is this (say you work with 64 bits=8 bytes values):

You may work with 8 byte values; but you should consider that memory and cache work with bigger units. Modern DRAM memory has bus of 64 bits (8bytes) wide (72 bits for 64+8 in case of ECC), and many transactions may use several bus clock cycles (burst prefetch in [DDR4 SDRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM) uses 8n - 8 * 64 bits. 
Many transactions between CPU cache and memory controller are bigger too and sized as full [cache line](http://docs.roguewave.com/threadspotter/2011.2/manual_html_linux/manual_html/ch03s02.html) or as half of cache line. [Typical cache line is 64 bytes](http://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/ACCU2011_CPUCaches.pdf#page=10).

> ```
> you read data at an address
> make some light weight CPU computation (so that CPU is not the bottleneck)
> then you read data at new address quite far-away from the first one
> ```

This method is not well suitable for modern out-of-order CPUs. CPU may speculatively reorder machine commands and start execution of next memory access before current memory access is done.

Classic tests for cpu cache and memory latency (lat_mem_rd from lmbench http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/lat_mem_rd.8.html and many others) use memory array filled with some special pseudo-random pattern of pointers; and the test for read latency is like  (https://github.com/foss-for-synopsys-dwc-arc-processors/lmbench/blob/master/src/lat_mem_rd.c#L95)

```
char **p = start_pointer;
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      p = (char **)*p; 
      p = (char **)*p; 
  ... // repeated many times to hide loop overhead
      p = (char **)*p; 
}
```

So, address of next pointer is stored in the memory; cpu can't predict next address and start next access speculatively, it will wait for read data from caches or from memory.

> I'd like to have an idea of the throughput (say in bytes).

It can be measured in accesses per second; for byte accesses, or word accesses or 8 byte accesses there will be similar number of accesses/s and throughput (bytes/s) will be multiplied for unit used.

Sometimes similar value is measured - [GUPS - guga-updates per second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giga-updates_per_second) (data in memory is read, updated and written back) with test of [Random Access](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projectsfiles/hpcc/RandomAccess/). This test can use memory of computing cluster of hundreds (or tens of thousands) of PC - check GUP/s column in http://icl.cs.utk.edu/hpcc/hpcc_results.cgi?display=combo

> A simple calculation assuming the RAM has typical DDR3 13 ns latency yields a bandwidth of 8 B/ 13 ns = 600 MB/s. But this raises several points:

RAM has several latencies (timings) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_timings

And 13 ns CAS is only relevant when you access opened Row. For random accesses you will often access closed row and T_RCD latency is added to CAS.

Comment: Good slides about memory organization: http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs250/sp16/lectures/lec07-sp16.pdf

Comment: Thanks. It makes the picture clearer. Any idea if cache misses before going to main memory introduce some latency? The Sandbridge document was a bit too cryptic for me...

Comment: @BenoitSanchez, https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/SandyBridge.html document says that memory access is "RAM Latency = 28 cycles + 49 ns (for open RAM page)." and "RAM Latency = 28 cycles + 56 ns (for random RAM page)." where 28 cycles are for full L3 cache latency (data from memory is forwarded through L3, L2 and L1 pipelines). 28 cycles are from CPU frequency (as caches are clocked at it) of 3.3 GHz, so it is like additional 10 ns for L3 latency and 50-56 ns for memory latency. 60-66 ns is like 15-16 millions accesses per second; for 1 byte accesses = 16 MB/s; for 4 byte access = 64 MB/s; for 8B =128

Comment: In multithreaded case there will be some bank parallelism to be used, and there will be bank contention too. You may expect 4x or 8x more (check how many banks you have)